# Why regression model doesn't learn?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have to create model which returns 3 numbers - the angles by which the 3d model is rotated. All models I use are rotated in the same way in the beginning. For this I rotate every model for a random degree from -15 to 15 and get this five times for each model (the color represents distance from "camera"). Each of these images has size [150, 150] and contain numbers from 0 to 255:

Top:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asHwQ.png)

Side:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJZgz.png)

Front:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H34ni.png)

Then I've created a model:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLDRD.png)

My training dataset is 30 models and for each I create 5 different rotations, so there's 150 samples. I used 105 for training and 45 for validation

Then, when I've tried to fit it for `100 epochs`, `batch size = 40`, `Adam, learning rate = 0.1`, error - `mean absolute error`. I use my custom metric, it's just `sum of abs(angle_true - angle_pred)`. It showed me this and something extremely similar during all training:

```
Epoch 95/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.8082 - metr: 25.7488 - val_loss: 7.8395 - val_metr: 16.2496
Epoch 96/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.8203 - metr: 28.0160 - val_loss: 7.8005 - val_metr: 16.1032
Epoch 97/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.7898 - metr: 21.8611 - val_loss: 7.8166 - val_metr: 15.6580
Epoch 98/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.7806 - metr: 18.9963 - val_loss: 7.8766 - val_metr: 15.1825
Epoch 99/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.7973 - metr: 21.3751 - val_loss: 7.8581 - val_metr: 14.8261
Epoch 100/100 3/3 [==============================] - 4s 1s/step - loss: 6.7750 - metr: 19.1987 - val_loss: 7.8100 - val_metr: 14.2220
```

There's what model actually predicts (five it's predictions vs five true angles):

```
[[-2.9442613  -0.54196733  2.4832273 ]
[-4.1728406  -0.60556126  1.6946273 ]
[-4.727777   -1.2003385   0.9080634 ]
[-3.125803    0.2552796   1.7383668 ]
[-5.6989026   0.5544905   1.539639  ]
[-3.6019537   0.29354924  1.2323818 ]]

[[ -4.  -8.   2.]
[-12.  -7.   4.]
[-13.  -4.  -3.]
[ -7.   2.  -4.]
[-13.   8. -12.]
[-15. -11. -11.]]
```

I recreated it some times and, as you can see, results were always close to one number and didn't varied. I don't know why they can't reach ewen 10.

I've tried to add `SeparableConv2D` after every `Conv2D` layer, to change loss function and to change learning rate to `0.01` and `0.001` but nothing changed. Why the model doesn't fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset is too small for regression task. Try to add more samples and use data augmentation (e.g. horizontal flipping, shifting, zooming, color jittering).

Comment: I have at all 90 3D models. Would it be enough if I create for each of them 5, so at all 450?

Comment: It would be better than 150, but It's hard to say if it would be enough